# Separate lines while reading a file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read a file with a VBA code - but when I try reading it, I get all of the text as one line:

```
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input As #FileNum

    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine    'Read The Data 1 Line At a Time
        If Len(DataLine) > 0 Then
            LineItems = Split(DataLine, vbTab)
        End If
    Wend
```

in this code, I get all of the text in "LineItems", as about 15K cells...
I tried using "vbNewLine" instead of "vbTab" but then I got all of the text in one cell - LineItems(0) (the same goes for using "vbCrlf")

so my question is - does anyone have an idea about how to get back the text Line by Line?

and if not - i thought about seperating the text into lines, and then for each line separate it by Tabs...
so what other ways are there for new lines except "vbNewLine"?

Thank You!!

Comment: You may need more flexibility in reading until you got clear about your input file. Try to find out about `Input`, `ReadLine`, `OpenTextFile` and `ReadAll`.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your txt file?

Comment: @Bramat Most likely your file does not used CR or CR-LF to delineate lines.  The VBA Input and Line Input methods may not work as expected if the file has not been written by the VBA Write # or Print # respectively.  You may be able to use the TextStreamObject property of the FileSystemObject.  Or you may be able to parse the string in VBA if you know what is being used to define the End of Line position.  If you can provide your text file, that would help in analyzing it.

Comment: sorry for the late reaction - apperantly the lines where seperated by "vbLf" and in each line i needed to seperate by "vbTab" - thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is carriage return (13 or 0xd) (used by vbscript and vba code), there is line feed (10 or 0xa)(used by notepad which ignores cariage returns), and there is cariage return followed by line feed which is the tradional line ending (send the printer head to beginning of line and advance paper by one line). All windows programs enter CR-LF pair but they tend to only read one.

In Unix they only store the LF relying on the reading program to add the cariage return. This saved one byte per line of storage.

If on 32 bit windows open the file in Edit in binary mode which shows characters.

```
edit /70 c:\windows\win.ini
```

♪◙ are the symbols for CR and LF. Don't copy them as here they are translated into unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I found no really good solution to this in my searches. In my problem I had to read files in Excel/VBA that have unknown origin and so could be Unix/Mac or windows style newlines. My solution was to create a VBA class the solves the problem, TextFileClass. Here it is. It works, but I would not call it thoroughly debugged. It is suitable only for moderate size files since they are kept in memory. It has only read and write modes, but a readwrite mode could be added with little trouble.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private fso As New FileSystemObject
Private file As TextStream
Private lines() As String
Private isOpenForWrite As Boolean

Public position As Integer
Public count As Integer

Public isOpen As Boolean
Public errMsg As String
Public lineSeparator As String

Function eof() As Boolean
    If position > UBound(lines) Then
        eof = True
    Else
        eof = False
    End If
End Function

Function fopen(fileName As String, mode As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As String

    errMsg = ""

    If mode = "r" Then
        isOpenForWrite = False
        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading)
        s = file.ReadAll
        file.Close

        lines = Split(s, vbCrLf)
        If UBound(lines) > 1 Then
            lineSeparator = vbCrLf
        Else
            lines = Split(s, vbCr)
            If UBound(lines) > 1 Then
                lineSeparator = vbCr
            Else
                lines = Split(s, vbLf)
                If UBound(lines) > 1 Then
                    lineSeparator = vbLf
                Else
                    errMsg = "Line separator cannot be determined"
                    fopen = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If

        position = 0
        count = UBound(lines) + 1
        fopen = True
        isOpen = True
    ElseIf mode = "w" Then
        isOpenForWrite = True
        Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, True)
        ReDim lines(0)
        lines(0) = ""
        fopen = True
        isOpen = True
        count = 0
        position = 0
    Else
        errMsg = "Mode not recognized"
        fopen = False
        isOpen = False
        isOpenForWrite = False
    End If
End Function

Function fclose() As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    If Not isOpen Then
        errMsg = "File is not open"
        fclose = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    fclose = True

    If isOpenForWrite Then
        For i = 0 To count - 1
            Call file.Write(lines(i) & lineSeparator)
        Next i

        file.Close
        Set file = Nothing
    End If

    errMsg = ""
    isOpen = False
    position = 0
    count = 0
    ReDim lines(0)
    lines(0) = ""
End Function

Function fread(ByRef line As String) As Boolean
    If Not isOpen Then
        errMsg = "File is not open"
        fread = False
        Exit Function
    ElseIf eof Then
        errMsg = "File is at eof"
        fread = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    fread = True
    errMsg = ""
    line = lines(position)
    position = position + 1
End Function

Function fwrite(line As String) As Boolean
    If Not isOpen Then
        errMsg = "File is not open"
        fwrite = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    Do While position >= count
        ReDim Preserve lines(count)
        count = count + 1
    Loop

    lines(position) = line
    position = position + 1
End Function
```